# Sudoku in WPF - What base element should I use for the Table?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm-light

I built a *very* basic Sudoku app in C#, XAML, and MVVM-Light.  The MainWindow has a 9x9 grid and 81 Textbox for each cell, and the MainViewModel has 81 int properties.  Not pretty.  The Sudoku table does not look like a classic table, there's no "thicker border" to differentiate each quadrant.

Now, I want to move on to the next level and make it pretty and practical.

Every cell content must be ?responsive? ie resize (font size) based on the width/height of the window.  I already started work on a CellUserControl that handles font color, background color, etc.

What should be the base for the Main window ? Grid, Table, ListBox, Custom ?

- I tried Grid and Table but usually ending up bumping to a dead end. The XAML becomes very verbose and repetitive.
- I remember MS showing of the power of WPF with ListBox displayed as a carousel, just by applying styles.  Is this a valid path ?
- Custom Control: is it overkill or it exists exactly for this situation ?

By the way, I'll be leveraging MVVM-Light and Data Binding a lot.

Comment: Use grid.  XAML is verbose and repetitive by its very nature.

Comment: Also, don't be afraid to construct the grid and cells using loops in code-behind if you want to avoid xaml's verbosity.

Comment: How do I take care of the lines ?

Comment: either put small rows and columns between each cell column, or make the lines by putting an outline in the cell using a rectangle with no margin on it.  If you want to do the thicker border between each box of cells, you can use a solid rectangle to fill a thin row/column and use rowspan/columnspan to make it extend to the length of the whole board

Answer (score 2):

Since all cells should have the same size, you could also use a [UniformGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid?view=netframework-4.7.2). As Leo Bartkus suggested, you could use code-behind to generate the cells and text boxes. To do this, start by creating a placeholder for the Sudoku table in XAML:

```
<!-- Placeholder for Sudoku table (filled in code-behind) -->
<Border x:Name="SudokuTable" />
```

Assuming you're using a `Window`, here's the code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private const int InnerWidth = 3;
    private const int OuterWidth = InnerWidth * InnerWidth;

    private const int Thin = 1;
    private const int Thick = 3;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeViewModel();
        InitializeSudokuTable();
    }

    public SudokuViewModel ViewModel => (SudokuViewModel)DataContext;

    private void InitializeViewModel()
    {
        DataContext = new SudokuViewModel(OuterWidth);
    }

    private void InitializeSudokuTable()
    {
        var grid = new UniformGrid
        {
            Rows = OuterWidth,
            Columns = OuterWidth
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < OuterWidth; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < OuterWidth; j++)
            {
                var border = CreateBorder(i, j);
                border.Child = CreateTextBox(i, j);
                grid.Children.Add(border);
            }
        }

        SudokuTable.Child = grid;
    }

    private static Border CreateBorder(int i, int j)
    {
        var left = j % InnerWidth == 0 ? Thick : Thin;
        var top = i % InnerWidth == 0 ? Thick : Thin;
        var right = j == OuterWidth - 1 ? Thick : 0;
        var bottom = i == OuterWidth - 1 ? Thick : 0;

        return new Border
        {
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom),
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Black
        };
    }

    private TextBox CreateTextBox(int i, int j)
    {
        var textBox = new TextBox
        {
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };

        var binding = new Binding
        {
            Source = ViewModel,
            Path = new PropertyPath($"[{i},{j}]"),
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
        };

        textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

        return textBox;
    }
}
```

The nested loop creates each `Border` and `TextBox` for the 81 cells. The border's thicknesses are determined based on the current cell's position. This will give you the typical Sudoku table look.

The text boxes are data-bound to the two-dimensional indexer property of the view model. Here's the view model:

```
public class SudokuViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly string[,] _values;

    public SudokuViewModel(int width)
    {
        _values = new string[width, width];
    }

    public string this[int i, int j]
    {
        get => _values[i, j];
        set => Set(ref _values[i, j], value);
    }
}
```

This indexer returns a string, but you may want to change it to an integer and do the appropriate conversions and error checks. In any case, it's using MVVM Light to raise the `PropertyChanged` event when the indexer property is updated.

I've created a repository with my solution here: https://github.com/redcurry/Sudoku.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I would do sudoku with a grid...

```
<Grid>


 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy1" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1"  Grid.Column="2"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy2" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1"  Grid.Column="4"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy3" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1"  Grid.Column="5"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy4" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy5" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy6" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy7" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy8" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy9" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy10" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox00_Copy11" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="1"  Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="3" Fill="#FF663003" Grid.RowSpan="12"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="7" Fill="#FF663003" Grid.RowSpan="12"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Fill="#FF663003" Grid.ColumnSpan="12"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Fill="#FF663003" Grid.ColumnSpan="12"/>
```

This is just the default textbox style.  You could make it different with a usercontrol, or you could make a custom style for the textbox by loading the xaml in Blend for Visual studio, rightclick the textbox and choose Edit Template.. -> Edit a Copy

Answer (score 0):

Great answers everyone, your ideas made me focus on a goal :)

Here's where I'm at, as of now.

XAML: I'm using the verbose XAML approach and a Grid.

Grid: 11x11 - (9x9 for the Sudoku cells + 2x2 for the borders).

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="2px"/>

            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="2px"/>

            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>

            <RowDefinition Height="2px"/>

            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>

            <RowDefinition Height="2px"/>

            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="11" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" Grid.RowSpan="11" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="11" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="11" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>

        <local:CellUserControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  DataContext="{Binding Path=Cells[0], Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
        <local:CellUserControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  DataContext="{Binding Path=Cells[1], Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
...
```

I'm lazy, so I ended up using an Excel Spreadsheet to enumerate the 81 cells, and use a combination Floor.Math, MOD and Concatenate :)

The next challenge was the refactoring of the 81 MVVM Properties to something more trivial.  In XAML: The syntax is {Binding Path=Cells[0]} and choose to put (for now) the property in the ViewModelLocator.

```
    public IList<CellViewModel> Cells
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<CellViewModel>(ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<CellViewModel>());
        }
    }
```

The XAML and code are clean.  I like it so far.  I'm still juggling the proper location for the IList - should it remain in the ViewModelLocator or should it be actually in the MainViewModel ?  I guess, to answer this question, I'll have to do some unit testing.

Many thanks.